# How is js loaded and removed in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, remove

Inevitably, I'm trying to improve our Magento 2.3.0 Pagespeed score. Most of the damage is being done by the excess of unneeded/unwanted js files.

Is there any simple way to remove js such as calendar.js, tooltip.js etc? It appears tooltip.js is loaded by jquery-ui.js but I can't find where calendar is loaded using grep, any suggestions please?

I expect deleting/renaming the unwanted js files will result in errors at best and a non functioning website at worst?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. In your layout file you can define to remove the js that is not required..
   This blog can help you in doing this 
   [https://meetanshi.com/blog/remove-js-and-css-in-magento-2-using-layout-xml/#:~:text=Programmatic%20Solution%20to%20Remove%20JS,to%20remove%20JavaScript%20and%20CSS](https://meetanshi.com/blog/remove-js-and-css-in-magento-2-using-layout-xml/#:%7E:text=Programmatic%20Solution%20to%20Remove%20JS,to%20remove%20JavaScript%20and%20CSS).
2. This thread may help you 
   [https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Programming/How-to-remove-js-files/td-p/48294#:~:text=To%20remove%20js%20file%20you,template%20file%20of%20that%20page](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Programming/How-to-remove-js-files/td-p/48294#:%7E:text=To%20remove%20js%20file%20you,template%20file%20of%20that%20page).
3. Adding some code snippet so that you can understand easily 
   After we override magento 2 customer module this is the path 
   app/design/frontend/Raptor/Desktop/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
/* M241= *PROGRAMMER - Vibhore *PURPOSE - UserDashboard */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
<head>
 <title>My Account</title>
 <remove src="js/tracking.js"/> 
 <remove src="js/tracking.min.js"/>
 <remove src="css/calendar.css"/>
 <remove src="css/calendar.min.css"/>
 <remove src="mage/calendar.css"/>
 <remove src="mage/calendar.min.css"/>
 <!--<remove src="css/styles-m.css"/>-->
 <remove src="css/header-footer.css"/>
 <remove src="css/header-footer.min.css"/>
 <remove src="css/style.css"/>
 <remove src="css/style.min.css"/>
 <remove src="css/brand.css"/>
 <remove src="css/brand.min.css"/>
 <remove src="fonts/font.css"/>
 <remove src="fonts/font.min.css"/>
 <remove src="css/owl.carousel.css"/>
 <remove src="css/owl.carousel.min.css"/>
 <remove src="css/owl.theme.green.css"/>
 <remove src="css/owl.theme.green.min.css"/>
 <!--<remove src="css/styles-l.css"/>-->
 <remove src="css/print.css"/>
 <remove src="css/print.min.css"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.
1. I've tried this method and it hasn't removed the js/css I specified. Cache has been cleaned but static content not regenerated yet. It's also not clear how to determine the path to use, I've just used the filenames i.e. (cssfile.css, jsfile.js), example path is pub/media/theme/web/css/header/cssfile.css
2. I had already seen this post but I think it applies to Magento 1 only.
3. This looks promising. I'll give it a try when I have a little more time.